# Got my own post in a review task

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

Not sure if this is a bug related to beta sites or if it's more extensive, but when I was going through review tasks, I got one of my own posts as a first post edit. I'm pretty sure this isn't supposed to happen.

Comment: Does it allow upvoting it? :)

Comment: Haha, I didn't think to try

Answer (score 5):

This probably shouldn't happen, but it's also a *very* localized problem - after the private beta ends, you'll need 125 reputation on the site in order to do any reviewing, and that excludes new users for at least a *little* while.

Beyond that, there's nothing you can *do* to your post in the First Posts queue that you wouldn't be able to do elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed now. You shouldn't get your *own* post in the First Posts or Late Answers review queues any more.

Answer (score -2):

Pretty much everyone's posts will be in the list, as everyone is a new user.

That review queue is for 'First posts by new users' which everyone is today :-)